# CKEditor unable to find getData function

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I have a boostrap form with a richtext field and when I open it up in edit mode I get this error in the console. Uncompressed files and aggregate is turn off. 
Anybody got some suggestions how to solve this ?

[image: CKEdit get data not a fuunction]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I had added some server side code in onClientLoad and that created a partial refresh of the page when the page was loaded and that broke CKEditor

[image: onClientLoad]